# Does state reinitialize to initial state everytime an action is dispatched in react using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, dispatch

For e.g. in the code below (NOTE: nothing particular in this code, just serves as an example):

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = {
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: []
};

const cartReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CartActionTypes.TOGGLE_CART_HIDDEN:
      return {
        ...state,
        hidden: !state.hidden
      };
    case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    case CartActionTypes.REMOVE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: removeItemFromCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
    case CartActionTypes.CLEAR_ITEM_FROM_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(
          cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id
        )
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Q1: Does state revert back to the INITIAL_STATE i.e.,

```
{
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: []
};
```

everytime an action is dispatched to this reducer?

Q2: So the state in the combinereducer would also reinitialize to initial state , say default state is returned in the  reducer? or to put it another way:
Q3: the state in the combinereducer corresponding to the particular reducer keeps getting reinitialized/set to the state defined by the most recently dispatched action , for e.g. in the code above  if CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM is the most recently dispatched action to the reducer

```
 case CartActionTypes.ADD_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
      };
```

then the state in combinereducer would be (based on the above case):

```
{
  hidden: true,
  cartItems: addItemToCart(state.cartItems, action.payload)
};
```

and hidden would be reintialized to  true regardless of what its value might have been in state due to earlier actions dispatched? So basically the latest action dispatched decides which current state values will be altered regardless of previous actions dispatched and the state values not altered by the latest dispatch are reintialized to the initial state?

Q:If im right in my understanding  then won't the various components in react that call the state values (e.g. using mapStatetoProps) only have access to the state values defined by the latest dispatch?

Comment: No; that would be madness--the initial state value is used only if no state is passed in. Components have access to whatever is in state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dispatch an action it will be sent to the reducer to compute the next state based on the **CURRENT STATE** and the **ACTION** dispatched.

Now your function `cartReducer` accepts 2 parameters, `state` and `action`. You are essentially telling the reducer function that if no state was provided then use `INITIAL_STATE`. So when your reducer function executes it will see if the value of state is `undefined`. If so then it will use `INITIAL_STATE` else it will use the provided state value, which is your current state.

You can check out more about default paramenters in JavaScript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). You can go over the redux core principles [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts)

Comment: Hi, Thanx for the detailed reply. So if my understanding is correct INITIAL_STATE is (usually) used only when the very first action is dispatched. And thereafter (usually) for subsequent dispatches  the reducer uses the current state or manipulates its values.

Comment: Yes `INITIAL_STATE` is used as the current state and then from thereafter subsequent states are computed based on the current state and the action dispatched.

Comment: @abh It would be helpful for future viewers if you could accept the answer if it was helpful and resolved your problem.